# Does my website have to comply with the legislation of every country in the world?

Tags: privacy, international

I have a website (cad-gis.online) running on an apache2 server on my raspberry pi connected to my router in Germany. It has some pretty simple html and css content and two javascripts using leaflet for a map and some pretty graphical user interaction. The website is available in german, french, english, spanish and portuguese. On it, I offer my services as GIS engineer and CAD draftsman. I bought the domain at Hostinger. There are no forms or whatsoever on the site.

1. Does apache2 register visitors ip adresses in log files?
2. Could the leaflet scripts maybe collect cookies?
3. Do I have to check the laws of every country? Does it depend on the languages? Could I get sued from anywhere in the world?

Comment: Any country can *claim* jurisdiction, but that might not be relevant. For example, I'll happily say gay gay homosexual gay regardless of what Saudi-Arabia, Russia, or Florida want. But since you're from Germany and targeting European customers, German rules (including GDPR, TTDSG) clearly apply. I would disable/reconfigure Apache httpd logging, would make sure my hosting provider acts as a "data processor" ("Auftragsverarbeiter"), and would only load resources (JavaScript, map tiles) from external servers after consent has been given (for motivation, read up on the "Google Fonts" case).